# Where to find current transactions per second statistic?

Tags: transactions-per-second

Is there any official website to find it?

I can't find it on internet.

Comment: Are you looking for the actual or theoretical TPS of the Cardano Network?

Comment: @gRebel not yet, I am new to Cardano :)

Answer (score 9):

I found [cardanowaves.com](https://cardanowaves.com/) the other day on r/cardano and it looks useful. Shows over 1M transaction in last 28 days, which is 35K/day. Agrees with previous answer; this may update more dynamically. It updates statistics from the blockchain.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

There's a chart [here](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1202328/average-number-cardano-transactions/), published on April 14th, which claims it's about 30-40k per day (so roughly 1 per 2-3 seconds), but I don't know how accurate it is.

[image]

<sub>(Note that the last five data points (on the website, I've cropped them from the image above) are misplaced; they're *March* dates instead of April.)</sub>

Comment: Is there any way to verify the accuracy of this screenshot? Is there no link to the source of this info?

Comment: @EGMSSE there's a 'show source' link at the bottom right, but it costs $60 a month ...

Answer (score 2):

You could find the average tps over an Epoch by looking at the transactions over an epoch through the official Cardano explorer [0]. Epoch 260 had 216117 transactions which equates to ~2 tps. This isn't the networks limit of course, there are many empty blocks and you can easily see blocks with > 15 transactions on the explorers homepage.

Saying this, I'd argue a far more interesting value is the bytes/sec because transactions can vary in size. You could find the current theoretical limit with `max_size_of_block / min_size_of_tx`. I don't remember these numbers off the top of my head though!

[0] https://explorer.cardano.org/en

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out [ADApools](https://adapools.org/epochs), lots of good statistics there

Answer (score 1):

go  there https://cardanoscan.io
in search epoch bar search last epoch .
you can see Transactions  . this is total Transactions in this epoch . you can division on current slot number .

Answer (score 1):

[The realtime page at adatools](https://adatools.io/realtime) shows a live count of transactions/hour. A hands-on way to get more detailed data is to run a cardano-node with Grafana monitoring, as described at [docs.cardano.org](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/logging-monitoring/grafana.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's also the epoch statistics in [adastat](https://adastat.net/).